# click on an image with selenium in python bindings

Tags: python, selenium

```html
<a onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13){ClientReportRpt…_ctl02.ActionHandler('Toggle','118iT0R0R0x1');}return false;" onclick="ClientReportRptMain_ctl02.ActionHandler('Toggle','118iT0R0R0x1');return false;" style="cursor:pointer;" tabindex="4">

    <img border="0" alt="+" src="/SIMS/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=cfsd…Type=ReportImage&ResourceStreamID=10.50.4000.0TogglePlus.gif">
    </img>
</a>
```

This is the part of the code and there are alot of similar images on the web pages where the value '118iT0R0R0x1' and tab index = '4' is not constant for the different position of the same image in the web page.
I am using Selenium in python bindings. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The anchor has the "onclick" handler, not the image. You need to "click" on the anchor.

```
anchor_element = browser.find_element_by_*(...)
anchor_element.click()
```

Where `anchor_element` explains itself. To find anchor elements you do this:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html

I cannot tell more, because your code fragment contains only two elements. In order to find the right elements, I would have to know more about which elements are you looking for...